# Return an object key only if value is true

Tags: javascript, object, underscore.js

How do i return an object key name only if the value of it is true?

I'm using underscore and the only thing i see is how to return keys which is easy, i want to avoid redundant iterations as much as possible:

example:

```
Object {1001: true, 1002: false}
```

I want an array with only 1001 in it...

Answer (score 60, accepted):

[Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) gets the keys from the object, then you can [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the keys based on the values

```
var obj = {1001: true, 1002: false};

var keys = Object.keys(obj);

var filtered = keys.filter(function(key) {
    return obj[key]
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/h7a97/)

Comment: Shorter: `keys = Object.keys(obj).filter(k => obj[k])`

Answer (score 16):

There is another alternative, which could be used with [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) library using two methods:

- `_.pickBy` - it creates an object composed of the object properties. If there is no additional parameter (predicate) then all returned properties will have *truthy* values.
- `_.keys(object)` - creates an array of keys from the given object

So in your example it would be:

```
var obj = {1001: true, 1002: false};
var keys = _.keys(_.pickBy(obj));

// keys variable is ["1001"]
```

Using [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) library, it would be very similar. You need to use [`_.pick`](http://underscorejs.org/#pick) and [`_.keys`](http://underscorejs.org/#keys) functions. The only difference is that `_.pick` would need to have predicate function, which is [`_.identity`](http://underscorejs.org/#identity).

So the code would be as follows:

```
var obj = {1001: true, 1002: false};
var keys = _.keys(_.pick(obj, _.identity));

// keys variable is ["1001"]
```

I hope that will help

Answer (score 5):

If you're trying to combine filtering and iterating over an object you're usually after [`_.reduce`](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce) (the Swiss Army Knife iterator):

```
var trues = _(obj).reduce(function(trues, v, k) {
    if(v === true)
        trues.push(k);
    return trues;
}, [ ]);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/2et6T/

Answer (score 3):

In case you will have an object, which has properties different than boolean, you may want to remove them with a filter:

@vsync remixed

```js
const obj = {1001: true, 1002: false, 1003: "foo"};
keys = Object.keys(obj).filter(k => obj[k] === true);

//keys = ["1001"];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
obj = {one: false, two: true, three: false, four: true}    
var values = Object.keys(obj).filter(key => obj[key])
console.log(values)
```

Comment: You should add a description of what you're doing here, rather than just posting some code. Explain why this solves the problem.