# How to show object from array which includes current key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array with many objects like this:

```
        "title": "Harry Potter and the Philosophers Stone",
        "price": "7.99",
        "image": "https://say-hi.me/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Digital-Harry-Potter-1.jpg",
        "id": 1,
        "author": "J.K.Rowling",
        "rating": 5,
        "onTop": false
```

Some of these objects have `onTop` key with value `true`. So how i can show objects using method `map` **ONLY** with value `true` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return an object key only if value is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25095789/return-an-object-key-only-if-value-is-true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the lodash library here https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#filter

Then you can do

```
var books = [
  { 'title': 'doggo', 'onTop': true },
  { 'title': 'catto', 'onTop': false }
];
 
const onTopBooks = _.filter(books, function(o) { return o.onTop; });
```

which should return you a new array with

`[{ title: 'doggo', onTop: true }]`

I would not use the map method because it returns a value for each element in the array and you would need an additional loop to remove the `null` items you dont want. `filter` or some method similar like `select` will be better here.

Additionally, you could just do something even more basic like:

```
let onTopBooks = []

books.forEach( book => {
  if (book.onTop) {
    onTopBooks.push(book) 
  }
})

return onTopBooks
```

Comment: Without lodash is real? I wouldn't like to install whole package because of one situation)

Comment: @Gover123 see edited answer. I would highly suggest keeping lodash around as it has a bunch of really useful functions. You could also just only import the one function you want to use if it really matters.

Comment: Uh, the lodash-less filter idiom is `books.filter(b => b.onTop)`, not `forEach`/`push` :)

Comment: It's too easy, the head doesn't work, it's time to sleep! Thank you bro! :)

Comment: @AKX yeah, in this situation it's easier to use filter method!)

Answer (score 1):

that ?

```js
const data = 
  [ { title:  'Harry Potter and the Philosophers Stone'
    , price:  '7.99'
    , image:  'https://say-hi.me/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Digital-Harry-Potter-1.jpg'
    , id:     1
    , author: 'J.K.Rowling'
    , rating: 5
    , onTop:  false
    }
  , { title:  'xyz'
    , price:  '7.99'
    , image:  'https://xyz.jpg'
    , id:     1
    , author: 'xyz'
    , rating: 5
    , onTop:  true
    }
  ]

const res = data.filter(e=>e.onTop)

console.log( res )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```