# Array - Extract label when value is true

Tags: javascript

I have this array

```
{ 1: NaN
2: NaN
120: NaN
121: NaN
122: NaN
125: NaN
126: NaN
127: NaN
128: NaN
129: NaN
130: NaN
131: NaN
132: NaN
133: NaN
134: NaN
135: NaN
136: NaN
602: NaN
603: true
604: true
605: NaN
607: NaN
608: NaN
609: NaN
610: NaN
612: NaN
613: NaN
614: NaN
615: NaN
616: NaN
617: NaN
765: NaN}
```

Question is simple: How can i *extract* the *label* (1,2,120,122,125..) when value is *true*?

Comment: That's not an array, that's an object.

Comment: see this:  [Return an object key only if value is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25095789/return-an-object-key-only-if-value-is-true)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter the keys where value is true

```js
var obj = { 1: NaN,2: NaN,120: NaN,121: NaN,122: NaN,125: NaN,126: NaN,127: NaN,128: NaN,129: NaN,130: NaN,131: NaN,132: NaN,133: NaN,134: NaN,135: NaN,136: NaN,602: NaN,603: true,604: true,605: NaN,607: NaN,608: NaN,609: NaN,610: NaN,612: NaN,613: NaN,614: NaN,615: NaN,616: NaN,617: NaN,765: NaN};

var values = Object.keys(obj).filter(key => obj[key])
console.log(values)
```

Comment: Heh, that's clever :D

Comment: 1 for loop for getting keys, 2nd for loop for filtering, can be done in single for loop.

Comment: @JagdishIdhate:  That single `for` loop would still have to push to a separate array. I'm not sure why you think the "single loop" is better, but this answer is just a single line of code...

Comment: @Cerbus its about cost, .filter & .keys needs 2 separate arrays to return results. I personally prefer performance over shiny code.

Comment: @JagdishIdhate: So I decided to [benchmark it](https://jsben.ch/jLpPD). Tuns out this approach is faster, also.

Not that you're gonna notice _any_ difference unless you're iterating over billions of entries. (474k iterations vs 399k is such an insignificant difference...)

Comment: Cool!! this is amazing, was not expecting results like this. Interesting to know why?

Comment: Your answer has: An array initialization, A loop, A `key` check, And finally a push into said array. This answer used built-in methods to iterate over the object's entries and filter. Those built-in methods are generally very well-optimized as far as performance is concerned.

Comment: @Cerbrus will it be correct to say that both approaches have a time complexity of `O(n)`?

Comment: @OwenKelvin: I'm not familiar enough with that notation to give you an answer in that format, but your answer performs fewer operations than the one that's got the separate array. (map->filter as opposed to iterate->filter->store value)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to convert the object to an array, then filter on values and get the corresponding keys:

```js
var obj = { 1: NaN,2: NaN,120: NaN,121: NaN,122: NaN,125: NaN,126: NaN,127: NaN,128: NaN,129: NaN,130: NaN,131: NaN,132: NaN,133: NaN,134: NaN,135: NaN,136: NaN,602: NaN,603: true,604: true,605: NaN,607: NaN,608: NaN,609: NaN,610: NaN,612: NaN,613: NaN,614: NaN,615: NaN,616: NaN,617: NaN,765: NaN};

var values = Object.entries(obj)   // Convert the object to a key/value array
    .filter(([_, value]) => value) // We only want the entries that have a truthy value.
    .map(([key]) => key);          // And of those entries, we only want the keys.

console.log(values);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write this:

```js
function getTruthyLabels(data){
  const truthyLabels = []
   Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value])=> value && truthyLabels.push(key))
  return truthyLabels
}
```

Working example:

```js
const myObject = { 1: NaN,2: NaN,120: NaN,121: NaN,122: NaN,125: NaN,126: NaN,127: NaN,128: NaN,129: NaN,130: NaN,131: NaN,132: NaN,133: NaN,134: NaN,135: NaN,136: NaN,602: NaN,603: true,604: true,605: NaN,607: NaN,608: NaN,609: NaN,610: NaN,612: NaN,613: NaN,614: NaN,615: NaN,616: NaN,617: NaN,765: NaN}

function getTruthyLabels(data){
  const truthyLabels = []
   Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value])=> value && truthyLabels.push(key))
  return truthyLabels
}

console.log(getTruthyLabels(myObject))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be done very much easily with [for-in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop

```js
var obj = { 1: NaN,2: NaN,120: NaN,121: NaN,122: NaN,125: NaN,126: NaN,127: NaN,128: NaN,129: NaN,130: NaN,131: NaN,132: NaN,133: NaN,134: NaN,135: NaN,136: NaN,602: NaN,603: true,604: true,605: NaN,607: NaN,608: NaN,609: NaN,610: NaN,612: NaN,613: NaN,614: NaN,615: NaN,616: NaN,617: NaN,765: NaN};

const arr=[]
for(key in obj){
  if(obj[key]){
   arr.push(key)
  }
  
}
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436) explains why people don't like to comment on downvotes. @AbsoluteBeginner: A downvote indicates that the answer is "not useful". That man mean that it's a bad answer, a bad practice, incorrect, broken or whatever. _"downvoting is a sort of pastime"_ is just a narrow-minded interpretation of downvoting.